# run ngrok using subprocess. how to use subprocess with both ip address and port?

Tags: python

```
def runNgrok():
   ngrokDir = "/home/ubuntu/ngrokFunctionalities"
   port = 8081
   ngrok_command = "ngrok"
   make_executable = str(Path(ngrokDir, ngrok_command))
   ngrok = subprocess.Popen([make_executable, 'http', 127.0.0.2, '-inspect=false','-bind-tls=true', port])
   atexit.register(ngrok.terminate)
   time.sleep(7)
   return True

File "ngrokRunKeepAlive.py", line 25
ngrok = subprocess.Popen([make_executable, 'http', 127.0.0.2, '-inspect=false','-bind-tls=true', port])
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have quotes around the IP. This is Python, so strings should be quoted.

Comment: This seems like a comment...

Comment: I can reword it to be an answer, my guess is that it'll solve the problem. But we need feedback from OP...